# Accessing individual values within rhandsontable

Tags: r, shiny, rhandsontable

I have a problem accessing individual values of a data frame that has been created from rhandsontable package. In the following code *`co[1]`* retrieves column 1 which is sensible, but then I try to access *`col[1,1]`* being row 1 column 1 produces *`missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed which is a bizarre error in this circumstance.`* I have tried accessing it with a list method namely *`co[[[1]][1]`* with no luck.

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

did_recalc <- FALSE

ui <- fluidPage(
  rHandsontableOutput('table'),
  dataTableOutput('result'),

  br(),
# tableOutput(),

  actionButton("recalc", "Return to original values")

)

server <- function(input,output,session)({


  a<-c(1,2,4,5,6,7)
  b<-c(1,2,4,5,6,7)
  c<-rbind(a,b)
  df1<-data.frame(c)

  #creates reactive values for the data frame
  values <- reactiveValues(data=df1)

  #if recalc --- which connects to an action button in the ui is hit, values goes back to original data frame
  observe({
    input$recalc
    values$data <- df1
  })

  #this changes the handsontable format to an r object
  observe({
    if(!is.null(input$table))
      values$data <- hot_to_r(input$table)
  })

  #important that you are using the values$data that have come from a reactive function
  output$table <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(values$data)
  })

    fn<-reactive({

     co<-data.frame((values$data))

    #output$tst<-renderTable(co[3,2]*2)    #So if I convert to a new data frame I can do operations on the columns
                                          #Still need to be able to access individual cells
      return(co)
  })


   output$result<-renderDataTable({
    fn()
  })   

}) 

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I get the feeling that the object I am trying to access is not clean or structured in the way I am assuming it is.

Comment: Is there a way of creating instances of reactive functions. I am not getting the desired results with using isolate.

Comment: Oddly enough, if anyone ever comes across the same problem. I solved it by doing co[desired row:length(colums)][desired column]